# JQuery IE Remove/Append Problem

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, video

I am having a lot of problems with Vimeo and IE. I have a custom video "player" functions like youtube - displays one video at a time with options to switch videos.

***First attempt:*** Hold each video in a div and show/hide them with JQuery fadeIn/fadeOut. Works in IE/FF/Chrome except in IE, switching between videos keeps the old video's audio playing as well as the new one. Not acceptable.

***Second attempt:*** hold each video in a div and remove/append each video as needed. But, in IE the video won't load the second time. Works fine in FF/Chrome.

I feel like I've tried everything, I'm at my wit's end. JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/4egZD/1/ (plays a video from Vimeo; my second attempt with remove/append )

Any help or alternatives are greatly appreciated.

Here's the code for non-JSFiddle'rs

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    // When any of our video description divs are clicked, play that video
    // for testing purposes, we only show one video
    // whenever a new video is clicked, we want to remove/append to stop the audio in IE
  $('#descript-1').click(function() {
      $("#video1" ).remove().appendTo('#videoHolder');
  });


});
</script>



<table border="1">
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #003388; color: white; font-weight: bold; padding: 2px; padding-left: 7px;" colspan="2">
<a name="videos">Watch Our Videos</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="videoHolder" valign="top">

<div id="video1" ><object width="400" height="225"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=23864606&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=0&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=0" /><embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=23864606&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=0&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="400" height="225"></embed></object>
</div>

</td>
<td style="margin-right: 5px; vertical-align:top;">
<div id="descript-1" style="width: 100%; margin: 5px; background-color: #999999; cursor: pointer;">
    <b>Play This Video</b><br />But why won't it play more than once in IE?
</div>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$('#descript-1').click(function() {
    var video = $("#video1");
    $("#video1" ).remove()
    video.appendTo('#videoHolder');
});
```

or

```
$('#descript-1').click(function() {
    var video = $("#video1").html();
    $("#video1" ).remove()
    $('#videoHolder').html("<div id='video1'>" + video + "</div>");
});
```

I've no idea if it will work or not, doesnt make sense but as everything dont make sense in IE you can give it a shot.

Also whats the problematic version of IE?

Comment: IE 7,8,9 - rebuilding the videoHolder's html does the trick, thanks buddy